# Add text to the photo using Photoshop action

Tags: excel, vba, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have a worksheet with the Image Filename (**Column A**) and text to be added(**Column B**) to the image respectively in two different columns.

Images has been saved in a separate folder

**Task:** Text defined in the **Column B** to be added to the right corner of the respective image defined in the **Column A**.

Is there any solution by using Photoshop actions and VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate the entire thing from Excel, using VBA. You won't need PhotoShop Actions.

In Excel's VBA Editor, you just need to make a reference to the Adobe Photoshop Object type Library, and use the automation objects top open your image file, add the text and save.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Please let me know if there is any script.